# Função javascript ordenação em ordem descrescente

Tags: javascript

Esta função javascript ordena em ordem crescente
Como eu faço para que ela ordene em ordem descrecente?

```
ordenaNomeCompleto: function(a,b){
    var ans = a.nome_completo.localeCompare(b.nome_completo);
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Essa função não ordena strings, ela apenas retorna se uma `string`,em termos de "valor" de cada caractere, é menor, igual ou maior que outra. Se `a` for menor do que `b`, ela retornará `-1`. Se `a` for equivalente a `b`, ela retornará `0`. Se `b` for maior que `a`, ela retornará `1`. Você deve usar esses fatores para realizar a ordenação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para fazer a ordenação decrescente basta trocar a ordem da comparação, trocando o `b` pelo `a` no sitio da comparação:

```
ordenaNomeCompleto: function(a,b){
    var ans = b.nome_completo.localeCompare(a.nome_completo);
    //        ^-----------------------------^
    return ans;
}
```

Isso funciona porque ao fazer `a.localeCompare(b)`, se o `a` é menor devolve um valor negativo, posicionando antes de `b` mas se fizer `b.localeCompare(a)` já irá devolver positivo na mesma situação, posicionando-o desta vez no fim.

Teste:

```js
const pessoas = [
  {nome_completo : "ana"},
  {nome_completo : "marcos"},
  {nome_completo : "carlos"},
  {nome_completo : "renan"},
  {nome_completo : "luis"}
];

const ordenaNomeCompleto = function(a,b){
    var ans = b.nome_completo.localeCompare(a.nome_completo); //a trocado com b
    return ans;
};

console.log(pessoas.sort(ordenaNomeCompleto));
```

Guardar o resultado numa variável para retornar logo de seguida não tem vantagem a menos que tenha um nome bom para um valor não muito evidente, que não é o caso. Por esse motivo seria melhor retornar direto o valor assim:

```
ordenaNomeCompleto: function(a,b){
    return b.nome_completo.localeCompare(a.nome_completo);
}
```

Que fica mais curto e fácil de ler.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!!